# ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)

Tags: ldap, redhat, centos7, rhel, slapd

I followed [RHEL7: Configure a LDAP directory service for user connection](https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-configure-ldap-directory-service-user-connection/) to configure openldap on CentOS Linux release 7.

First I create the `/etc/openldap/changes.ldif` file and paste the content with replacing the password of course with the previously created password.

Then I get to send the new configuration to the slapd server using the command

```
# ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/changes.ldif
```

Once I do that I get the following error:

```
# ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/changes.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config"
modifying entry "olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config"
modifying entry "olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config"
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
```

All the files are readable for the user slapd is running as.
What's wrong there? I couldn't find anything useful to feed SEARCHENGINE with.

It's been a while that I've been looking for a solution but at the moment all what I found is two people

- [Re: Error 80 with ldapmodify](https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201603/msg00090.html)
- [ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=67443)

Having the same problem and asking the same question but no answers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my specific case, I was having this error and I literally spent *days* scouring the Web for an answer. It turned out in my case that **the order matters**. The correct order was:

1. `olcTLSCACertificateFile`,
2. `olcTLSCertificateKeyFile`,
3. `olcTLSCertificateFile`.

Until the order of the attributes in my file was the one above, I was having that dreaded and unhelpful "ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)" message.

I tried to detect permission errors using `sudo -u ldap nano <path to each file>`. All was fine for each file.

nano revealed that the files were in DOS format: I converted them to have Linux line endings, to no avail.

In all I read, there was a question as to whether the certificate file was in the proper PEM format. I could not check that, maybe that it's also a cause for this error.

The only thing that worked was commenting out some lines in the file until I saw changes after running `ldapsearch -H ldapi:// -Y EXTERNAL -b "cn=config" -LLL -Q -s base`.

Note also that I "compressed" the changes in my file to a single change. What I mean with "compressed" is that instead of having three changes, I had only one: instead of this (I'm using Ansible, so this is actually a Jinja2 template)

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: {{ cert_parentdir_ca_chain }}/{{ cert_filename_ca_chain }}

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: {{ cert_parentdir_wildcard_cert }}/{{ cert_filename_wildcard_cert }}

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: {{ ldap_cert_parentdir_key }}/{{ cert_filename_key }}
```

I had this

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: {{ cert_parentdir_ca_chain }}/{{ cert_filename_ca_chain }}
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: {{ ldap_cert_parentdir_key }}/{{ cert_filename_key }}
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: {{ cert_parentdir_wildcard_cert }}/{{ cert_filename_wildcard_cert }}
```

HTH.

Comment: I solved the problem just use in the correct order first key then cert. And it worked for me. 

    dn: cn=config
    changetype: modify
    replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
    olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/myldap.kart.com.key 
    
    dn: cn=config
    changetype: modify
    replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
    olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/myldap.kart.com.cert

Comment: I am unable to get it to work.  Itried re-ordering the keys, as advied (CACert, Key, Cert), but no dice....still have the same error.

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak: I suggest you read my post again and maybe, follow the links in the question. A likely cause to me, if you are certain you reordered things and it still doesn't work, is a filesystem permission issue. Also, try using a more verbose logging setting.

Comment: For me it was permission issues on the certs causing the error  `chown openldap:certbot /etc/letsencrypt/ -R` The order seems to not matter in my setup

Comment: Similar to @mRyan,  I had permissions issues with the certificate key.  Specifically, openldap needs to be able to read it.  In my case I changed it's group to openldap and set it's permission to 640 per https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-ldap-with-tls

Comment: Using the correct order did not work for me to modify all 3 entries at once. What I had to do was do a delete operation on olcTLSCertificateKeyFile, then do a separate add operation to add it with the new value.